# How to find limit of recursive complex sequence?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0 = x_0 + i y_0$ be a given  complex number.

I am trying to find the limit of the sequence

$$ z_{n+1} = {1\over 2}( z_n + z_n^{-1})$$

for $x_0 <0$ and $x_0>0$ respectively.

I know that I should find $-1$ and $1$ respectively but even if I know the result I don't know how to go about calculating this limit.

> Please could someone explain to me how to calculate the limit of a
>   recursively defined sequence in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} z_n$ exists and equals $L$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} z_{n+1}=L$ too.  Take the limit of both sides of that equation, use limit laws (and $L$) to get an equation involving $L$.  Finally, solve for $L$.

Comment: Thank you very much. With your help I could find $L=1$ or $L=-1$. Do I have to do proof by induction to show that if $x_0 <0$ then $L=-1$ or is there an easier argument?

Comment: I guess I mean "shorter" argument, induction is of course as easy as possible already.

Comment: @Anna, when you take the limit of both sides you get $L=\frac{1}{2}(L+\frac{1}{L})$.  Then just solve for $L$.  This of course assumes that $L\neq 0$.

Comment: @Anna, note that $L=\pm 1$ are solutions to the equation... multiplying by $L$ you have a quadratic (at most 2 real solutions).

Comment: @Anna, Note that regardless of what $x_0$ and $y_0$ are, the only possible limits of $z_n$ are $\pm 1$.  You just need to decide which is which.  If $y_0=0$, then notice that the sign of $z_n$ never changes, that makes the "purely real" case easy.

Comment: Yes I know all that. But I am asking how to prove the two cases: that the case $x_0 <0$ is the one converging to $-1$ and the case $x_0>0$ is the case converging to $1$. I did it using induction but I am asking if there is a shorter way.

Comment: @Anna, you should specify that in your question then instead of asking "how to solve in general"

Comment: I am asking a question about your answer. I don't understand why I should add a question about your answer into my question.

Comment: Never mind, I managed to work it out.